# SkinnablePopUpContainer not destroyed

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4, flex4.5

I am monitoring my internet connection. When there is no service available I get an Event from my URLMonitor. I am listening to this event and calling a function that opens a SkinnablePopUpContainer. It is a very simple Component I have no listeners attached to it and it is defined only inside the function. When the user clicks the button inside the SkinnablePopUpContainer I close the component and try to destroy it using all possible ways I know of. When I check the Profiler Tool from Flash Builder the SkinnablePopUpContainer is still there. How do I destroy this component freeing the memory it is using.

Here is the listener function:

```
        protected function onNoServiceAvailable(e:*):void
        {
            var noserviceWindow:NoInternetError = new NoInternetError();
            noserviceWindow.open(this,false);       
            noserviceWindow.x= 0;
            noserviceWindow.y= 0;
            noserviceWindow.width = SharedObject.getLocal('localObj').data.appMeasures.appWidth;
            noserviceWindow.height = SharedObject.getLocal('localObj').data.appMeasures.appHeight+200;
        }
```

and here is my SkinnablePopUpContainer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SkinnablePopUpContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
         xmlns:nxTextInput="nx.components.extended.nxTextInput.*"
         xmlns:nxButton="nx.components.extended.nxButton.*"
         backgroundAlpha="0.4"
         horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"  width="100%" height="100%"> 
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        protected function loginButton_clickHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            loginButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,loginButton_clickHandler);
            this.close();
            var ob = this;
            ob = null;
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Panel title="Fehler" 
         horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"  color="white">
    <s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" gap="20"
              height="100%" width="100%">
        <s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('assets/nxInspect/mobile/assetsCI/redAssets/alert_80x80.png')"  id="iconBitmpapDownOnline" verticalCenter="0" />
        <s:Label id="serviceFailure" text="Keine internetverbindung." width="90%" styleName="interactable" textAlign="center" color="white"/>
        <nxButton:NxButton id="loginButton" label="OK" width="100%" height="100" click="loginButton_clickHandler(event)" styleName="alert"/>
    </s:VGroup>

</s:Panel>
```

Comment: The profiler (in Flash Builder) had a way to show "loitering objects" and from that list of objects you could see what the "gc_root" of each object was. "gc_root" ("garbage collection root" or similar name) is the thing that is keeping the object pinned in memory. Now days, I guess people use Adobe Scout, perhaps it has a similar feature?

Comment: Also, be advised that the Flex framework (in the past) itself could cause memory leaks, b/c some parts of the framework kept references to objects. Most of those have been addressed by now... In your case I might suspect the `PopupManager` class, or the embedded image in your pop up, any data binding, use of resource bundles, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the line var ob = this; just creates a reference variable to "this". Setting this variable to null will not make it delete itself. It will just re-reference the variable you just created to null again, so those 2 lines are useless.

Because you've contained your local variable noserviceWindow within the scope of the function onNoServiceAvailable, it should automatically be marked for Garbage Collection when there are no more references to it. If your profiler is recognizing it's existence, then there is probably another reference to it somewhere in your code.